# How can I avoid error when setting elsif range condition?

Tags: ruby, range

```
def Summer
    @summer = true
    puts "Your fruit are ripe for the picking."
    if @tree_age == 1..5 && @tree_age > 0
        @oranges = 5
    elsif @tree_age == 6..15
        @oranges = 20
    else
        @oranges = 50
    end
end
```

I'm trying to ensure a tree between a certain age range gives x oranges, however I'm stuck with the following error referring to my elsif statement:

```
Orange_tree.rb:14: warning: integer literal in conditional range
```

I have also tried using an if greater than && less than conditional statement, can somebody please explain what this error means, and how to reach my solution.

Comment: Instead of adding a thank you message (which is against the rules) you should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer that helped you most by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @idmean, you asked the OP to select your answer a mere 16 minutes after the question was posted (albeit guised in general advice). Eats, don't be intimidated by such requests. There is no hurry whatsoever in selecting an answer. A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better answers, and imo is discourteous to those still working on their answers when the selection is made. Many of us on SO wait at least a couple of hours (sometimes much longer) before selecting an answer. Note you can change your selection whenever you like.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I completely agree with you and normally don’t post any comments like this before a few days have passed. This was an exception because the user [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34532875/revisions) his question to thank me and apparently (looking at his profile) didn’t knew how to accept an answer. I also regularly comment the same text at questions where the same has happened even if I haven’t answered it (That’s the reason why it’s a general advice). It’s not by intention to get more reputation or outdo an answer, I actually up voted the better answer below myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `include?` instead of [`==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) to determine if the given number is within the range:

```
def Summer
    @summer = true
    puts "Your fruit are ripe for the picking."
    if (1..5).include?(@tree_age) && @tree_age > 0
        @oranges = 5
    elsif (6..15).include? @tree_age
        @oranges = 20
    else
        @oranges = 50
    end
end
```

`==`:

> Returns true only if obj is a Range, has equivalent begin and end
>   items (by comparing them with ==), and has the same exclude_end?
>   setting as the range.

Which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect!

Answer (score 8):

You have a few problems:

- You'll want to put your ranges in parenthesis when other operators or methods are nearby. Your current error comes from Ruby parsing `elsif @tree_age == 6..15` differently than you expect - it's treating it as `(1 == 6)..15`, and `false..15` obviously doesn't make any sense.
- To test a number is within a range, use `(1..5) === num`, not `num == (1..5)`. [`Range#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is defined to test that the `Range` includes the right hand side, while [`Fixnum#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D) and [`Fixnum#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) both just test that the right hand side is numerically equivalent.
- You don't need to test `@tree_age > 0`. You're already testing that it's in `1..5`.

You could also consider a `case` statement for this, which can be a bit easier to read. `case` does its comparisons using `===`.

```
@oranges = case @tree_age
           when 1..5 then 5
           when 6..15 then 20
           else 50
           end
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful, and I've jotted your answer in my notebook. I had put && > 0 just to exclude any weird values that may somehow lead to a negative age, not really sure if it was necessary.

Comment: I like your answer for the third point and case statement, but disagree with the first two bits of advice. The lack of parentheses around ranges does not necessarily invite errors or make the code hard harder to follow as you yourself have shown by your case statement! :-) "...use `(1..5) === num`, not `num === (1..5)` should read "...you could write `(1..5) === num` (not `num === (1..5)`), but that should be avoided, as it is much clearer to write `(1..5).include?(num)` or `(1..5).cover?(num)` or `num >= 1 && num <= 5`.

Comment: To each their own. Parentheses are commonly helpful for me trying things like `1..5.each`, which fails trying to evaluate `5.each`.

Comment: If you took your own advice you'd put the ranges in parentheses in the case statement. Should you? Of course not. Nor is the OP's lack of parentheses a problem. Clearly, in many situations parentheses not needed, or are desirable for improved readability, just not everywhere.

Comment: There wasn't a typo, but I've clarified why not - thanks. I'm leaving the parentheses advice because Ruby gets confused about the OP's original code: `a = 0; a == 1..5 && a > 0 #=> false..false`

Comment: Better, imo: "not `num == (1..5)` or `num === (1..5)`". It still looks amusing to see you contradict your own advice in the `case` statement.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the lines that say == with a range.

```
if ( 10  == 1..11) # throws integer literal in conditional range warning
    puts "true"
end
```

If you did this instead

```
if ( 10.between?(1, 11))
    puts "true"
end
```

Comment: Eats may wish to read the doc for `between?`. Do you think he/she will be able to find it? You should provide the link: [Comparable#between](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) and explain `Fixnum.included_modules #=> [Comparable, Kernel]`.